# Rails scope ordered ascending not responding in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In the model I have:

```
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
scope :ascending, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }
```

In the view:

```
<ol class="notices comments">
  <%= render notice.comments.ascending %>
</ol>
```

In the model, when I change `default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }` to `default_scope -> { order(created_at: :asc) }`, the notices respond as expected and display in ascending order instead of descending. However, when I change `scope :ascending, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }` to `scope :ascending, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }`, it doesn't change anything. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `order`, it just adds another component to the ORDER BY clause. So if you have your default scope and add your `ascending` scope, you end up with this ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY created_at desc, created_at asc
```

The `created_at asc` be effectively ignored because it is unlikely that there will be any ties to break from the `created_at desc` ordering.

You probably want to use [`reorder`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder) in your scope to completely replace the ORDER BY:

```
scope :ascending, -> { reorder(created_at: :asc) }
```

This assumes that the only ordering in effect comes from the default scope so it can lead to surprises if you say something like:

```
Model.order(:whatever).ascending
```

The `order(:whatever)` would be removed by the scope.

I tend to think that default scopes are almost always a bad idea because they hide things from you, doubly so when the default scope includes ORDER BY adjustments. I'd drop that default scope and make the callers explicitly specify their ordering.